# PDF Images not at 100% quality on LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

When I export as PDF on LibreOffice I've got a poor image quality on all the images and all the documents I made.

I've checked the option "Lossless compression" on the export preferences.

I take the screenshots with Shutter.

Also I have a friend who shows me a PDF exported like I'm doing and their PDF looks awesome...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I have used your image, and it doesn't seem to have been degraded after exported to PDF (see http://i.stack.imgur.com/4mJkU.png). Please check if the "reduce image resolution" option is checked. I'm using LibreOffice 4.1.1.2 (from PPA).

Comment: As a side note, `return $num % 2 == 0;`?

Comment: LO 3.6.6 here. I second carnendil. No problems, either. What LO version are you using, @Lloople?

Comment: I'm using LO 4.0 but I don't think it's a problem with LO. I think it's a problem with my Linux system, I also see another friend doing this with Ubuntu 13.10 and also have the same poor quality. Can be because the graphic card driver os something else? My graphic card is an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500 and I don't know what driver I have.

Comment: not sure this can help.... but in LO i can see different results for images when exporting pdf from odt files (no problems) or from a doc file (poor image resolution), actually this concerns graphics (borders) of cells pasted from Calc into writer they are properly exported to pdf only from .odt file (not from .doc) (lubuntu, LO 4.132)

Comment: Is it possible that this is an issue with the image rendering in your PDF viewer and that the image in the PDF is fine?

As a troubleshooting method have you confirmed that tools other than LibreOffice can convert it without experiencing the same issue when viewed back with the same viewer?

Comment: Also it's not a LO bug, I can reproduce it on Windows with MS Office, I think it's because my graphic card, but not sure because years ago I was able to export images in PDF with quality... Maybe my computer gets broked or the drivers today have a bug. Don't know but thanks for all your help and time.